# Print function arguments separated by a delimiter other than space

Tags: bash

I need function which prints parameters with non-standard delimiter (as opposed to the spaces created by `my_func() { echo "$@"; }`). Something like this:

```
$ my_func foo bar baz
foo;bar;baz
```

The number of parameters varies and I not need a trailing delimiter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my_func() {
  local IFS=';'       # change the separator used by "$*", scoped to this function
  printf '%s\n' "$*"  # avoid reliability issues innate to echo
}
```

...or...

```
my_func() {
  local dest                 # declare dest local
  printf -v dest '%s;' "$@"  # populate it with arguments trailed by semicolons
  printf '%s\n' "${dest%;}"  # print the string with the last semicolon removed
}
```

<sub>With respect to "reliability issues innate to `echo`" -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and note that bash's conformance with that standard varies with both [compile-time](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Optional-Features.html) and [runtime](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) configuration.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Actually why  IFS=';' printf '%s\n' "$*" (in one line) doesn't work?

Comment: *In one line*, you're telling the shell to put `IFS` in the environment while it runs `printf`, not while it expands the `"$*"` when generating printf's arguments. This is the same as how `(value="foo" echo "$value")` and `(value="foo"; echo "$value")` differ; the former puts the variable in `echo`'s environment, but echo doesn't look at its environment in determining contents to emit -- it looks at its argument list.